# Blog page - display latest post top of the page

Tags: php, blogs

What I need to do that my latest posts go automatically to top of the page? Now latest post go bottom of the ealier posts.

php:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="blog">
        <div class="grid_9 float-left">
            <?php foreach($posts->results as $post): ?>
            <div class="post box_shadow">
                <h2><a href="<?php echo URL::to('uutiset/post/'.$post->id.'/'.\Laravel\URL::slug($post->title)) ?>"><?php echo $post->title ?></a></h2>
                <small><?php echo date('d-m-Y',strtotime($post->date)) ?></small>
                <p><?php echo Str::limit_word($post->content, 40); ?></p>
                <a href="<?php echo URL::to('uutiset/post/'.$post->id.'/'.\Laravel\URL::slug($post->title)) ?>"><?php echo Lang::line('home.blog_read_more', array(), $lang)->get() ?></a>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            <?php echo $posts->links()?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer" class=" box-shadow">
        <?php echo stripcslashes($setting->footer)?>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am still newbie so could you give advice what line I need modified or add and where?

Answer (score 0):

That's how your array is sorted. options: [reverse the array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) or do a for loop starting from the last index going to 0.

Something similar to below:

```
`$posts->results` has all of your posts

Replace the foreach with a for.

$count = count($posts->results);
for($i = $count-1; $i <= 0; $i--) {
    $post = $posts->results[$i];
    //display post
}
```

The simplest but probably less efficient way is to reverse the array right before the foreach loop.

Comment: I am still newbie so could you give advice what line I need modified or add and where?

Answer (score 0):

If it is exactly the opposite of what your looking for try running [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) on it before hitting the loop.